# Eclipse on Ubuntu Linux build errors after opening in editor

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, include

I have checked out a C++ project in my Eclipse CDT Indigo release 20120216-1857 on Ubuntu 12.04.
When I try to build or run it immediately, without opening any file from the project, it just builds nicely and it runs just right.

When I open one of the .h or .cpp files in the editor however, I get more and more simple include errors, like `Function 'assert' could not be resolved` or `Type 'string' could not be resolved`.

I can not fix these errors by disabling automatic build, or by cleaning the project. Restarting Eclipse would resolve the build problem, but after opening files the errors appear again.

Comment: I had the same issue in the projects where the templates was used. I believe that it is the eclipse's CDT bug. Try to clean and build the project again also check the dependencies.

Comment: Could you be any more specific on the dependencies I have to check? Do you mean dependencies for Eclipse? or do you mean includes for the C++ project?
Cleaning didn't help.

Comment: I mean that your project could have some dependencies on the third party libraries and the sequence of (list entries) them plays a role in the compilation process. Just check the project's properties in C++ build section. Check all the needed libraries needed for your project are available on your system.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I fixed the problem by removing the Debug default configuration. Probably the debug/releases profiles were interfering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add assert library . It'll oke

```
#include <assert.h>
```